# Tkinter - Remove and Set Border of Widget

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to remove the border of a text widget at the beginning of a callback, and then based on the result of the rest of that callback, I want to set the border to red if a certain variable has a certain value.

The following is what I have tried, but once the border is set to red, it never gets erased at the beginning of the callback.

```
from tkinter import *
import time



class GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.cnt = 0;
        self.master = master
        self.test_button = Button(self.master, command=self.tb_click)
        self.test_button.configure(
            text="Calc", background="Grey",
            padx=50
            )
        self.test_button.pack(side=TOP)

        self.test_text = Text(self.master)
        self.test_text.configure(background ="White",height = 2, width = 15)
        self.test_text.pack(side=TOP)



    def tb_click(self):
        self.test_text.configure(highlightthickness = 0)

        self.cnt += 1
        time.sleep(3) #simulate long running process

        if(self.cnt>1): #check result of long running process
            self.test_text.configure(highlightbackground = "red")
            self.test_text.configure(highlightthickness = 4)



root = Tk()
root.title("Test Border")
main_ui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press button then `mainloop()` runs your function and it waits to the end of your function and then it redraws window and all widgets in window. This way it has to redraw it only once for all changes. It needs less time and window doesn't blink.

But using `root.update()` you can force `mainloop()` to redraw window earlier

```
self.test_text.configure(highlightthickness=0)
root.update()
```

Comment: It worked! Are there any potential issues that you know of that this might cause? For instance, if I try to update root from a different thread?

Comment: most GUIs doesn't like to work in threads - they should run in one thread - not always it has to be main thread. If other thread has to change something in GUI then it should send message to main thread and main thread should change it. You can use module [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) to send to main thread, or simply use global variable(s) for this. And main thread would need to use `root.after(millisecond, function_name)` to execute periodically function which will get message from thread and change GUI.